# Decimal points in calculator android

Tags: java, android, string-comparison

I am creating a calculator app in android. The issue is how can I check for existence of two decimals in a single numeric value . Currently my calculator allows inputs such as `1.2.3` which is illegal . It must allow  a decimal if an operator has been used. Eg `1.1+2.2` is legal but `1.1.1+2.2` isn't.
Here is my code for decimal handling:

```
public class TrialCalculator extends AppCompatActivity implements Button.OnClickListener {
    Button btn1, btn2, btnBack, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6, btn7, btn8, btn9, btn0, btnPlus, btnMinus, btnMul, btnDiv, btnEquals, btnClear, btnDecimal, btnPercent;
    EditText calcResult;
    double number = 0;
    private char opcode = '1';

    private void handleDecimal() {
        if (opcode == 0) clear();
        if (calcResult.getText() == null) {
            calcResult.setText("0.");
            calcResult.setSelection(2);
        } else {
            String txt = calcResult.getText().toString();
            if (txt.lastIndexOf(".")<txt.length()-1) {
                calcResult.append(".");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling the `buttonDot` from `onClick` Method.

Comment: You should show a little bit more code. In particular, the method shown here should be inside a class and you should show all variable declarations.

Comment: `handleDecimal` will be called when the `.` button is pressed. Correct?

Comment: Yes thats correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to have a flag which keeps track of the decimal:

```
class MyCalculator {
    private hasDecimal = false;

    // ...
}
```

Set this flag to `true` the first time that the user types a decimal. Then check the flag to see if a decimal has been previously typed.

Of course, this only works if you are responding to each key press directly rather than getting the entire input from a `EditText` after the user has typed the entire number.

Comment: Yes finally boolean variable was the only approach that did the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex with `matches` function

`\\d*` mean match zero or more digits

`(\\.\\d+)?` match a `.` followed by one or more digits , `?` mean matches between zero or one times of given group

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/bojndV/3) : note with `matches` function in java, we don't need `^` start and `$` ending anchors

Code

```
if (txt.matches("\\d*(\\.\\d+)?")) {
   // number has one decimal
  }
else{
   // number has more than one decimal
}
```

---

**Note:**  if you don't want to allow values like `.5` then use `\\d+` instead of `\\d*` as

`\\d+(\\.\\d+)?`

As suggested by @Code-Apprentice , if you want to accept values like `4343.` etc
you can use

```
\\d*(\\.\\d*)?
```

Using text watcher

```
calcResult.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        boolean flag = s.toString().matches("\\d*(\\.\\d*)?");
        if(!flag){
            // calcResult.setError...
            // you display a toast 
        }             
    }
});
```

---

**Update :** To match multiple  values with operators , you can use

```
(\\d*(\\.\\d*)?([+\\-*%\\]|$))*
```

[**RegEx demo**](https://regex101.com/r/kYh3aU/3)

Test Cases

```
String pat="(\\d*(\\.\\d*)?([+\\-*%\\]|$))*";
System.out.println("4.5-3.3+3.4".matches(pat));
System.out.println(".5".matches(pat));
System.out.println("4".matches(pat));
System.out.println("4.5.5-4.4".matches(pat));
System.out.println("4.44.5+4.4.4".matches(pat));
System.out.println("4.".matches(pat));
```

Output :

```
true
true
true
false
false
true
```

Comment: Wouldn't that also go to the else branch if there is no decimal point?

Comment: Similarly, the `\\d+` after the decimal can be `\\d*` instead if you want to allow numbers like `5.`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice but then this will allow values like this `43434.` , `1.` with a digit followed by a decimal point and then nothing

Comment: @PavneetSingh exactly.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice i intentionally excluded these values ,but if OP want then i will modify the regex or your advise is here too :)

Comment: Yes, my comment is mainly for the OP. I expect any calculator app I use to allow such input.

Comment: I want to disable input in the number if it already contains a decimal and not check for the existence of a  second decimal.

Comment: @BismeetSingh then you have to use TextWatcher  and inside `afterTextChanged` match your input using regex and if the match failed you can set the the error  on edittext or display a toast . let me update my code

Comment: @BismeetSingh you like , if input is a valid input then , a message or error should be shown to user , right ?

Comment: It should not permit a second "."input in a number.Eg it should allow 1.2 or .5 but not 1.2.3

Comment: @BismeetSingh according to this , if the input is invalid then , you can show set error on edittext or display a toast and later on button click , you can use that `flag` on button click to check the valid input or can again match against pattern

Comment: Using "\\d*(\\.\\d+)?" does work but it doesnt allow decimals even after an operator has been displayed. Eg 1.1+2.(doesnt allow the decimal after 2);

Comment: @BismeetSingh obviously didn't mention anything about operator before , you have to mention your all retirements , so add your requirements clearly

Comment: I added the requirements.

Comment: @BismeetSingh next time don't forget to do this  and can try and use the update if you want

Answer (score 0):

`lastIndexOf` returns -1 if the character is not found in the string. So your condition `txt.lastIndexOf(".")<txt.length()-1` is always `true`. You could change it to

```
txt.lastIndexOf(".") == -1
```

Answer (score 0):

To check for existence of two decimals in a single no then split the string by decimal.

for e.g.,

```
String txt = calcResult.getText().toString();
String[] decimals = txt.split("\\.");
if(decimals.length > 2) {
// txt contains more than 1 decimal.
// Your logic ..
}
```